# On C++ pointers and references, clarification needed

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What of the below is wrong please?

It is my understanding that a pointer represents an address of something of some type.

So, `int i = 18`, a pointer to it is `int *pI = &i;`

The following 2 declarations are valid

```
void foo (int &something) // Will accept an address of something
void bar (int *something) // Will accept a pointer to something
```

When we declare a function as

```
void bar (int *something)
```

We better send a pointer to something. Indeed, `foo(pI)` works.

Following the same logic, when looking at

```
void foo (int &something)
```

We should send it an address of something pointing to an int as an argument, so then:

Why is `foo(&i)` wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `void foo (int &something) // Will accept an address of something`

This is incorrect: `int&` is a *reference*, a concept that is similar to pointers in certain ways, but not at all identical.

References are similar to pointers in that a value can be changed through a reference, just like it can be changed through a pointer. However, there is no such thing as "null reference", while NULL pointers are very common.

When you call a function that takes a reference, you simply pass the variable the reference to which you are taking - no `&` operator is required:

```
void foo (something); // "something" must be a variable
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `void foo (int &something)` takes a [reference variable](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html), not a pointer.

You call it exactly the same as you would call `void foo (int something)`, except that `something` is [passed by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference), not [by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value).

Answer (score 0):

> void foo (int &something) // Will accept an address of something

No, though I can understand the confusion.  That function takes a *reference* to `int`.  References are guaranteed to be non-null in a well defined program.  It is similar conceptually to a pointer, but semantically different.

To call that function you don't need to do anything special.

```
int i = 10;
foo(i);  // passed to foo by reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in C++ the *&* means "reference type" in the context of a function prototype as you are using it here. Your function:

```
void foo (int &something)
```

is actually specifying that an integer reference type should be passed, so you would simply call this function like this:

```
foo(i);
```

Note that in this case you are still passing the address of *i* into the function, but you are doing it as a reference type rather than a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* different meanings for `&`.

The first is to create a pointer from an existing variable.

The second is to make a reference.

Even though they both use the same character, they are two completely different things.